# Subtracting the average value of 60 row from the other rows in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rows, subtraction

I have a DataFrame imported with pandas consisting of 2135 rows and 518 column. Now I want to take the mean of the first 60 rows and subtract these values from the other rows. So far I used this:

```
mean = df[1:60].mean()
```

to take the mean of the first 60 rows. I tried to subtract it by just using:

```
df[61:2135] - mean
```

but that doesn't work. I have tried a couple of more things but I can't seem to figure it out. Maybe it's the shape of the dataframes because mean has the shape (517,) whereas df[61:2135] has the shape (2072,518).

Comment: post raw data and code that I can run to reproduce your issue, my answer has shown that this should've worked

Comment: here is a link to the file i use: http://www.filedropper.com/csvdata

Comment: Where's your code?

Comment: Well your csv has no header columns which is fine but your rows terminate with `;;;` which may be the problem in the final column

Comment: When importing I skip the first row, therefor the second row bevond the headers of the columns (they are masses of ions)

Comment: As I asked many moons ago, where is your code to load your df?

Comment: Oh sorry, it is: df = pd.read_csv ("csvdata.csv", sep=",",skiprows=1)

Comment: did you try my updated answer

Comment: yes, whenever  I use a command in the form df[517] it says KeyError: 517

Comment: You need to also pass `header=None` `df = pd.read_csv ("csvdata.csv", sep=",",skiprows=1, header=None)` because it looks like your second row are not valid column names to me

Comment: That did the job, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data looks malformed, the last column has trailing semi colons `...;;;` you need to replace these and cast back to float:

```
In [44]:
df[517] = df[517].str.replace(';;;','').astype(float)
df.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 2134 entries, 0 to 2133
Columns: 518 entries, 0 to 517
dtypes: float64(518)
memory usage: 8.4 MB
```

then what you tried will just work

Additionally your second row doesn't look like a valid column row so you need to pass `header=None` to `read_csv`:

```
df = pd.read_csv ("csvdata.csv", sep=",",skiprows=1, header=None)
```

Comment: When I try what I wrote I get the error: ValueError: can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar